# How I can implement this relation between data grid rows in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, criteria

I am looking for componet like this 
[image: Grid_related_rows]
this picture has taken from source control query builder.
I would like to make relation between rows.As you see in this picture, we can make join between two separated sql statement ((work items type=issue and state=closed) or automated=12) 
and we can show the relation between rows by two bracket easily.
How I can implement this idea , which component I should use? 
Actually I am developing criteria builder for Sql Queries.
Please help me to implement this idea.

Comment: I hope you're not expecting a full-blown solution...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're implementing SQL query builder I probably don't need to tell you about trees ;-)

The brackets can be probably implemented as a custom column in whatever grid control you're using. Without more info it's hard to help.

Implementing SQL query builder can be tricky - you might want to look around for an existing control. It might end up cheaper to buy rather than build.